# Remove exact text using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this circumstance:

```
name.update(name.innerHTML + "<br /><div id='clearselection' style='color:red;padding-left:5px;font-size:11px;'>[ Clear Selection ]</div>");
```

and I need to remove the break and the div after it. I tried using:

```
selector.down(div).remove();
```

But it didn't work. No, I can't use jQuery :( it must be prototype. Any ideas?

I basically get the result of:

```
<span>test<br /><div id='clearselection' style='color:red;padding-left:5px;font-size:11px;'>[ Clear Selection ]</div></span>
```

But then I need to get back to:

```
<span>test</span>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  I've read it 3 times and can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Added some code, hopefully that helps explains things better.

Comment: You haven't given enough surrounding context.  Please go to http://jsfiddle.net, and paste all of the html and javascript into the  appropriate sections, so we'll have a working example.  Then paste the link to you fiddle here.

Comment: `selector.down(div).remove();` should be `selector.down('div').remove();` or more specific `selector.down('div#clearselection');`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but:

1. You cannot really operate on .innerHTML injected string with Prototype.js since they will not get registerd as DOM elements. Instead of `name.update(name.innerHTML +...)`, for example, include scriptaculous Builder and use something `name.insert({ bottom: Builder.node('div', { id: clearselection, style: 'color:red;padding-left:5px;font-size:11px;' }, [ '[Clear Selection]']) });`
2. If you want to remove something within a string, you can use `string = string.gsub(/regex_pattern/, '');` (using `null` instead of `''` may fail in lower MSIEs)
3. If you want just to clear whitespaces, there's a Prototype method `Element.cleanWhitespace()`, http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/cleanWhitespace/

And btw... **prototype.js > jQuery** when you just want the **utility framework**. Always.